# Warning: Undefined array key "name" error while connecting PHP file to database MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, post

I am trying to get form data input from the user and store it into my database.
But while getting the data from the form into php using POST method, I got an unexpected error

Here I am attaching the php file code image
[index.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cNTk.png)

I literally copy this example from youtube tutorial and tried running it and I get this error message:
[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4vsp.png)

Check my code if there is some mistake in it.

I am trying to get data from html form using POST method in PHP so that my sql query will execute properly but run into this error.

Comment: As per [ask], do not upload code as images. Thanks